# Kubuntu doesn't reconnect to Wifi after waking up from sleep

Tags: linux, kde, wifi, suspend, sleep

I just installed Kubuntu on my laptop and it's working fine so far, except the wireless connection is not switched on after waking up from sleep. I do have to click "Enable wireless" so that it reconnects.

For that matters, my laptop is an Asus N56VZ and the wireless connection requires Personal WPA2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should check the power management options. You'll probably find something there about disabling wireless when it goes to sleep.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is solved now. Indeed it looks to have disappeared after uninstalling `powertop`. Other users may encounter similar problems with alternatives as well.

Comment: Answer your own question, so others looking for it won't see "0 answers"...

Answer (score 1):

It appears `powertop` was responsible for disabling the Wifi connection. Uninstall it / Configure it and you'll get your Kubuntu box automatically reconnect to Wifi after waking up from sleep.

Have a great day!

Comment: I know this isn't exact to your issue, but it's along the same lines. You could still benefit from using powertop by possibly adding a small script like what is mentioned in [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=149683) thread.

Comment: You should also accept this answer, so everyone knows the question has a solution now.